Type of output from \cs_new:Nn
I wonder what the output from this function would be.  Is it a string ?
\cs_new:Nn \align_adrs:n
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        {l}     {left}
        {L}     {left}
        {r}     {right}
        {R}     {right}
        {left}  {left}
        {right} {right}
      }
    {left}  % default for non-matching case.
 }


It returns left if called as \align_adrs:n {l} and similarly for the other cases. The tokens returned are not a string, but the catcodes in the even-numbered braced groups are preserved.

So they are tokens.  But somehow the string \flushleft is made for execution.  I struggle to understand about catcodes.  What is even-numbered braced groups are preserved about ?

In the use case I showed in my previous answer, the (expanded) output is passed as part of the argument to \begin{flush#1}, so you get flushleft if the match is with l, L or R.

Yes, I understand that.  But I was thinking of strings making the command  flushleft or flushright.  But understanding the return of a token list,  what would the token be ? And how do even-numbered braced groups get into all this ?  I miserably fail to follow your answer and its connection to the construction of flushleft and flushright.

I added some explanations in my previous answer.

What would the token returned by \align_adrs:n be like ?

Let's experiment:
\ExplSyntaxOn

\exp_args:Ne \tl_analysis_show:n { \str_case:nn { x } { {x}{a{b}-c} {y}{[]&} } }
\exp_args:Ne \tl_analysis_show:n { \str_case:nn { y } { {x}{a{b}-c} {y}{[]&} } }

The console will answer
The token list contains the tokens:
>  a (the letter a)
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  b (the letter b)
>  } (end-group character })
>  - (the character -)
>  c (the letter c).

The token list contains the tokens:
>  [ (the character [)
>  ] (the character ])
>  & (alignment tab character &).

The first argument to \str_case:nn is “stringified” and compared with the odd-numbered braced groups (which are likewise stringified). At the first match, the contents of the corresponding even-numbered braced group is returned, with the category codes preserved.

Do you mean that I get the token list composed of the tokens l, e, f, t; and r, i, g, h, t ?

@Bulldrive Yes, that's it.
